# Trouble querying specific text field in mongoDB using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo-3.x

I have stored around 120 text files in a mongoDB database through connecting my local instance to mongodb cloud. I used pymongo to automate the insertion of the contents of each text file into mongodb cloud. The collection of 120 documents looks like this:

```
'''
{ _id:ObjectID(....),
  nameTextdoc.txt:"text_document",
  content: ['Each sentence stored in an array.','...']
'''
```

I am trying to retrieve the nameTextdoc.txt field and content field by using:

```
'''
collections.find_one({'nameTextdoc.txt': 'text_doc'}) 
'''
```

in a python script using pymongo. For some reason I receive None when I run this query. However, when I run:

```
'''
collections.find_one({})
'''
```

I get the entire document.

I would like to get assistance on writing a query that would retrieve the entirety of the text file by querying the name of the text file. I have periods in my key names, which may be the specific reason why I cannot retrieve them. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is a way to query fields with a `dot` embedded in the field name - use the `$getField`.

Comment: Okay, so rather than go the python pymongo route, I should query mongodb directly?

Comment: My above comment applies to pymongo also. Its generally not recommended to use periods (or dots) within a field name. The dot has a special meaning in MongoDB querying.

Comment: hmm okay, thank you. I think I'll spend some time reformatting the names of the fields and remove the period. It will make things easier in the long run. I just inserted a document with a field name without a period and was able to query it successfully.